# Internationalization - listing and adding languages

Tags: java, resources, internationalization, resourcebundle

I'm making an application in Java. This application can be internationalized using `ResourceBundle`s. I want to allow user to choose the language that he want to the application have. And there's a question: how to list available languages for the program? I don't want to use `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`, because I don't know if the app's got a .properties file for the chosen language. There's also the second question: can I add an ability to add additional language files outside the .jar file? And the last question: is there any better internationalization solution?

Regards

Comment: *"I want to allow user to choose the language that he want"* It is provided free by the OS.

Comment: No... I mean: "I want to allow user to choose the language FOR MY APPLICATION that he want" :)

Comment: Just the simple question: why you want to force user to choose his/her language instead of detecting a Locale? I really don't know why so many people do that mistake.

Comment: No, I don't want to force user to choose his/her language. I want to detect a locale, but if the user wants to choose other locale, I want to allow him/her it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just store a fixed list of supported locales in some constant of your application. If you need to make this dynamic, I see two solutions:

- use a properties file listing the supported locales, and load them from this properties file at startup.
- iterate through the available locales (or languages), try to load a corresponding bundle properties file (using `Class.getResourceAsStream()`), and consider that the locale is supported if you get an InputStream, and not supported if you get null.

You could let the user add a bundle by putting some directory in the classpath, in addition to your jar. Drop the properties file in this directory (respecting the package hierarchy), et voilà.